# Generate HMAC signature for Google Maps at work API on Apigee Edge

Tags: javascript, python, google-maps, apigee, hmacsha1

I am trying to generate a valid signature for the google maps API on Apigee edge.

I've tried using a javascript callout to no avail. I am able to generate signatures but they don't match what google expects. I suspect it has to do with the encoding of the crypto key.

I can't get python scripts to deploy at all (already opened a support case for that).

I'm using CryptoJS which I believe does not binary encode the key. Has anyone already solved the problem of calling the Google Maps API for Work with an HMAC signature?

Comment: Have you tried building and executing the .js locally (or in something like JSFiddle) to validate that the signature you're creating is indeed valid?

Comment: Yes, and it appears that the script doesn't produce valid signatures. Google's sample Python script seems to work so, I'll see if I can get that to work in Apigee. 
I suspect that CryptoJS doesn't decode the key to binary before creating the hash, meaning that it is, in essence, the wrong key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work with Python. My solution is based mostly on Google's example script. I had to make changes to the line to decode the signature in order for it to work on Apigee Edge. Of course, this will only work for those who have a paid Apigee Edge account as the free version does not support Python.